# Bootstrap icons not showing up

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm developing an angularjs app using bootstrap as the UI. I've downloaded a tutorial from YouTube which i'm following and the problem i'm facing is my icon is not showing up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.5" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid"> 
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> Hello Plunker!</h1>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        Nav
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: BS 5 has icons (I don’t know BS 4). There are several ways to include these in your DOM. 

https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/1-circle-fill/

As far as why these icons aren’t appearing in your DOM you should confirm the icons are being included in your BS payload. Not sure if you referencing a CDN or local files but step 1 should be to confirm they are available for your css/html.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that you use **Font Awesome** icon pack, since Bootstrap v4 glyphicons are no longer supported. I'm not even sure that I saw a website that uses Bootstrap's glyphicons. Almost every website that uses icons, are the Font Awesome ones. Take a look, I'm sure you will find what you need.

Font Awesome : http://fontawesome.io/icons/

If that's not enough, you can use the SVG ones, but from a different repository : https://simpleicons.org/

Or these ones, also from different repository : http://konpa.github.io/devicon/

Answer (score 2):

For me, I had installed the node module but not the icons themselves, which needed this in my application.scss:

```
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css");
```

I got it from [here](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/#install)

Answer (score 1):

As of Bootstrap 4, the glyphicons font, that was packaged with the Bootstrap deliverable in version 3, was removed.

More information, along with alternative options, can be found [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#components).

Answer (score 1):

I installed `bootstrap-icons` via the npm package manager. But, I had to import `bootstrap-icons.scss` in my `index.scss` file.

For example -

index.scss

```
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.scss';
```

**Note** - Make sure to provide current path to node_modules respective to your index.scss file.